# EJB Timer retry Interval

Tags: timer, ejb, websphere

Is it possible to increase the retry interval of EJB Timer in WAS ? When I m getting a database timeout error, the Timer was keep retrying after every 30 seconds which I dont want to be like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "Retries and missed timeouts" section of the [Creating timers using the EJB timer service for enterprise beans](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html) topic in the knowledge center.  Specifically:

> First retry attempt is immediate. Subsequent retry attempts occur on
>   the configured scheduler poll interval for persistent timers, and on
>   the configured retry interval for non-persistent timers.

See the [EJB timer service settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/uejb_timerservice.html) and [Configuring a timer service](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tejb_timerservice_v8.html) topics in the knowledge center for more information on configuring the poll interval and other timer service settings.